# Mocha runs previous tests

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to run mocha unit tests. Even though I replace some of the test files in my testrunner.html when I run mocha the results from my previous test files are also displayed in the terminal.

```
$ mocha
/Users/s/Documents/Mocha/test/aarrayTest.js:12
  var expect = chai.expect;
                   ^

ReferenceError: chai is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/s/Documents/Mocha/test/aarrayTest.js:12:20)
```

The test aarrayTest.js was actually replaced by another test file in testrunner.html. I don't understand why it is still considering aarrayTest.js.

The result displayed in the browser refers to the original test file given in the testrunner.html.